# MAMP SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away on Mac Catalina

Tags: mysql, magento2, mamp

I googled and the solution was to add/edit this:
    [mysqld]
    wait_timeout=100000
    max_allowed_packet = 256M

into this file /etc/mysql/my.cnf and but i cant find etc, where is the etc?

[image]
mysql_error_log.err

> 2020-02-26T13:09:54.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to
>   '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err'. 2020-02-26T13:09:54.6NZ
>   mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57 2020-02-26T13:09:54.943202Z 0 [Warning]
>   TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>   --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2020-02-26T13:09:54.943551Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv
>   is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are
>   disabled 2020-02-26T13:09:54.943611Z 0 [Note]
>   /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26) starting as
>   process 2189 ... 2020-02-26T13:09:54.949688Z 0 [Warning] Setting
>   lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for
>   /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
>   2020-02-26T13:09:54.952118Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
>   GCC atomic builtins 2020-02-26T13:09:54.952159Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses
>   event mutexes 2020-02-26T13:09:54.952176Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin
>   __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier 2020-02-26T13:09:54.952187Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use
>   zlib 1.2.11 2020-02-26T13:09:54.952681Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of
>   pools: 1 2020-02-26T13:09:54.952894Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32
>   instructions 2020-02-26T13:09:54.955089Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing
>   buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
>   2020-02-26T13:09:54.971785Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization
>   of buffer pool 2020-02-26T13:09:54.990800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest
>   supported file format is Barracuda. 2020-02-26T13:09:55.005564Z 0
>   [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.005739Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1'
>   size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.024819Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is
>   now 12 MB. 2020-02-26T13:09:55.025655Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo
>   rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.025678Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback
>   segment(s) are active. 2020-02-26T13:09:55.025883Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Waiting for purge to start 2020-02-26T13:09:55.079934Z 0 [Note]
>   InnoDB: 5.7.26 started; log sequence number 2551871
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.080171Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s)
>   from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.080257Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.086927Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Table
>   mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name
>   table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade 2020-02-26T13:09:55.086990Z 0
>   [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch
>   in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.090242Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because
>   of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without
>   certificate and private key 2020-02-26T13:09:55.090273Z 0 [Note]
>   Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.090660Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.090721Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
>   2020-02-26T13:09:55.090868Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>   '::'. 2020-02-26T13:09:55.093848Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load
>   completed at 200226 21:09:55 2020-02-26T13:09:55.173772Z 0 [Note]
>   Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events 2020-02-26T13:09:55.173947Z 0 [Note]
>   /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.7.26'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port:
>   3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) 2020-02-26T13:10:18.977842Z 2
>   [Note] Got an error reading communication packets

Answer (score 2):

You're using MAMP so you will need to create a new file in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/` called `my.conf`

Your full file path will be `/Applications/MAMP/conf/my.conf` and the contents will be:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout=100000
max_allowed_packet = 256M
```

Once you've added the file you probably need to restart your mysql server in MAMP